# Get interpolated value between 0 and 1 with result strongest at certain point

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to write a shader. I do miss an algorithm though.

The goal is to define a value and have the texture be strongest at that vertex.y value.

Example : 
Vertex values range from 0 to 1.
Now I define a value i = 0.5.
What I want now is the full texture color for a vertex at y = 0.5 and have the texture fade out the more vertex.y goes to 0 or 1, so at 0 and 1 the texture has a strength of 0.

This is what I have right now, not much, the formula for weight0 is obviously wrong, as it only works in one direction.

```
       fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {

            float y = i.height; // vertex y value between 0 and 1

            float weight0 = 1 - abs ( y - _center0); //weight, should be strongest at _center0

            float4 tex0 = tex2D(_tex0, i.uv);                

            float4 finalColor = tex0 * weight0;

            return finalColor;
        }
```

So, how do I calculate the weight0 that it is strongest at _center0 and falls off in both directions.
Maybe this is obvious, but I can't seem to come up with something useful.

Thanks.

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to interpolate between your values but how about a [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function)?

Comment: The good old Gauss. Looks familiar, I should have known this. I'll look into it.

Comment: By the way, `float weight0 = 1 - 2 * abs ( y - 0.5);` should give you a correct linear interpolation too. You can then raise your weight to any power you like to produce a sharper or a more mellow drop-off. Or you can use `float weight0 = sin(y/pi);`, the possibilities are endless...

Comment: Had some problems with Gauss, but I got linear interpolation working. The formula I use is float weight = pow(1 - clamp(0.0,1.0,2.0 * abs ( y - center + 0.5)), falloff); Works for me. Thanks :)